# How do you create a new AVAsset video that consists of only frames from given `CMTimeRange`s of another video?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Apple's sample code [Identifying Trajectories in Video](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/identifying_trajectories_in_video) contains the following delegate callback:

```
func cameraViewController(_ controller: CameraViewController, didReceiveBuffer buffer: CMSampleBuffer, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation) {
    let visionHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cmSampleBuffer: buffer, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
    
    if gameManager.stateMachine.currentState is GameManager.TrackThrowsState {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Get the frame of rendered view
            let normalizedFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
            self.jointSegmentView.frame = controller.viewRectForVisionRect(normalizedFrame)
            self.trajectoryView.frame = controller.viewRectForVisionRect(normalizedFrame)
        }
        // Perform the trajectory request in a separate dispatch queue.
        trajectoryQueue.async {
            do {
                try visionHandler.perform([self.detectTrajectoryRequest])
                if let results = self.detectTrajectoryRequest.results {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.processTrajectoryObservations(controller, results)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                AppError.display(error, inViewController: self)
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

However, instead of drawing UI whenever `detectTrajectoryRequest.results` exist (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetecttrajectoriesrequest/3675672-results), I'm interested in using the `CMTimeRange` provided by each result to construct a new video. In effect, this would filter down the original video to only frames with trajectories.

What would be a good approach to transferring only frames with trajectories from an `AVAssetReader` to an `AVAssetWriter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you identify a trajectory in captured video frames or from frames decoded from a file you may not have the initial frames in memory any more, so the easiest way to create your file containing only trajectories is to keep the original file on hand, and then insert its trajectory snippets into an `AVComposition` which you then export using `AVAssetExportSession`.

This sample captures frames from the camera, encodes them to a file whilst analysing them for trajectories and after 20 seconds, it closes the file and then creates the new file containing only trajectory snippets.

If you're interested in detecting trajectories in a pre-existing file, it's not too hard to rewire this code.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    
    var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter!
    var assetWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
    var assetWriterStartTime: CMTime = .zero
    var assetWriterStarted = false

    var referenceFileURL: URL!
    var timeRangesOfInterest: [Double : CMTimeRange] = [:]

    func startWritingFile(outputURL: URL, initialSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
        assetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: outputURL, fileType: .mov)

        let dimensions = initialSampleBuffer.formatDescription!.dimensions
        assetWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264, AVVideoWidthKey: dimensions.width, AVVideoHeightKey: dimensions.height])
        
        assetWriter.add(assetWriterInput)

        assetWriter.startWriting()
        
        self.assetWriterStartTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(initialSampleBuffer)
        assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: self.assetWriterStartTime)
    }
    
    func stopWritingFile(completion: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        let assetWriterToFinish = self.assetWriter!
        self.assetWriterInput = nil
        self.assetWriter = nil
                
        assetWriterToFinish.finishWriting {
            print("finished writing: \(assetWriterToFinish.status.rawValue)")
            completion()
        }
    }
    
    func exportVideoTimeRanges(inputFileURL: URL, outputFileURL: URL, timeRanges: [CMTimeRange]) {
        let inputAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputFileURL)
        let inputVideoTrack = inputAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
        
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        
        let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
        
        var insertionPoint: CMTime = .zero
        for timeRange in timeRanges {
            try! compositionTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: inputVideoTrack, at: insertionPoint)
            insertionPoint = insertionPoint + timeRange.duration
        }
        
        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputFileURL)
        exportSession.outputURL = outputFileURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = .mov
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
            print("export finished: \(exportSession.status.rawValue) - \(exportSession.error)")
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        let inputDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)!
        let input = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: inputDevice)
        let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        
        session.addInput(input)
        session.addOutput(output)
        
        session.startRunning()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20) {
            self.stopWritingFile {
                print("finished writing")
                
                let trajectoriesFileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] .appendingPathComponent("trajectories.mov")

                self.exportVideoTimeRanges(inputFileURL: self.referenceFileURL, outputFileURL: trajectoriesFileURL, timeRanges: self.timeRangesOfInterest.map { $0.1 })
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Lazily create a single instance of VNDetectTrajectoriesRequest.
    private lazy var request: VNDetectTrajectoriesRequest = {
        return VNDetectTrajectoriesRequest(frameAnalysisSpacing: .zero,
                                           trajectoryLength: 10,
                                           completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }()
    
    // AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate callback.
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                       didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if !assetWriterStarted {
            self.referenceFileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] .appendingPathComponent("reference.mov")

            startWritingFile(outputURL: self.referenceFileURL, initialSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)
            assetWriterStarted = true
        }
        
        if assetWriterInput != nil && assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
            assetWriterInput.append(sampleBuffer)
        }
        
        do {
            let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cmSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)
            try requestHandler.perform([request])
        } catch {
            // Handle the error.
        }
    }
    
    func completionHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        guard let request = request as? VNDetectTrajectoriesRequest else { return }

        if let results = request.results,
           results.count > 0 {
            NSLog("\(results)")
            for result in results {
                var fileRelativeTimeRange = result.timeRange
                fileRelativeTimeRange.start = fileRelativeTimeRange.start - self.assetWriterStartTime
                self.timeRangesOfInterest[fileRelativeTimeRange.start.seconds] = fileRelativeTimeRange
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I'll be looking into removing duplicate trajectory results, and improving performance wherever possible.

Comment: The `Vision` framework seems to give you multiple "in progress" trajectories, so you end up with a lot of repeats. This sample only keeps the latest & presumably longest version of a trajectory.